# Outputting incorrect value from do while loop

Tags: c#, loops, do-while

I'm trying to write a program which determines if a number is coprime to the e number. A loop tells the user if the number they entered is coprime to the e number, if it's not it makes them input another number until it is coprime. However when I test the program, if I input a number which isn't coprime to begin with, and then input a coprime number, the output of the number shows the original number I inputted(the number which isn't coprime). I don't understand why its outputting the wrong number.

```
 namespace example
{
class Program
{
    class GFG
    {
        static BigInteger _gcd(BigInteger e, BigInteger euiler)
        {
            // Everything divides 0 
            if (e == 0 || euiler == 0)
                return 0;
            if (e == euiler)
                return e;

            if (e > euiler)
                return _gcd(e - euiler, euiler);
            return _gcd(e, euiler - e);
        }
        static void coprime(BigInteger e, BigInteger euiler)
        {
            if (_gcd(e, euiler) == 1)
                Console.WriteLine("Co-Prime");
            else
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Co-Prime");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter another number which is Co-Prime");
                e = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                coprime(e, euiler);

            } while (_gcd(e, euiler) != 1);
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also noticed if I input an incorrect value twice and then a correct value, it doesn't continue the rest of the program, it say it's coprime but then keeps asking for a coprime number

Comment: You might want to relook at gcd calculation method. http://www.functionx.com/csharp2/examples/gcd.htm

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173413/calculating-gcd-for-2-integers

Comment: You may be over complicating things by using recursion and loops within a recursive method. Did you do all of that on purpose? I think your solution to the problem is all over the place and therefore coding the solution is all over the place too. Thus debugging is a challenge too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter "e" that you send to coprime function passed as value type, so any change you do to it don't change the "e" in the main function, if you want to do so you need pass it by ref.

Change your cod like this

coprime function:

```
static void coprime(ref BigInteger e, BigInteger euiler)
{
    if (_gcd(e, euiler) == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("Co-Prime");
    else
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not Co-Prime");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter another number which is Co-Prime");
        e = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        coprime(ref e, euiler);
    } while (_gcd(e, euiler) != 1);
}
```

the call in main:

```
coprime(ref e, euiler);
```